# trigger other parts of code to continue (C#)

Tags: c#, interrupt-handling

I am modifying an old, large (and un-documented) program in C# that uses an API to talk on a serial bus.

Is there some way of letting OnIndication trigger SendRepeatRequest to continue?
I would like to avoid polling a flag with wait Xms as response time varies greatly and I need quick responses.

```
//Pseudocode
public void SendRepeatRequest(int X)
{
  SendToAPI();
  // Wait until API responds, usually a few ms but can take 1-2min
  // loop X times
}

//this is activated by the API response
public void OnIndication()
{ 
// Handle request from API...
// Tell SendRepeatRequest to continue
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `OnIndication` run on a different thread than `SendRepeatRequest`?

Comment: They run in the same thread as far as I can tell.

Comment: So probably all you need to do is set a flag in OnIndication, and test that flag in the SendRepeatRequest wait loop.

Comment: Isn't a wait loop quite CPU intensive and should be avoided? My idea with this post is to avoid that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the Task library (introduced in .NET 4.0 under the System.Threading.Tasks namespace). It has a variety of threading operations to do this pretty easily.

I believe the following section might help (or get you started).

```
public void OnIndication()
{
Task doWork = new Task(() =>
    {
        // Handle request
    });

    Action<Task> onComplete = (task) =>
    {                
        SendRepeatRequest(X, args)
    };

    doWork.Start(); 

    doWork.ContinueWith(onComplete, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());                       
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to solve the problem described by the OP.

Comment: I don't quite think this works, but I may be wrong. I was thinking of something like: 
`public void SendRepeatRequest(int X)
{ SendToAPI();
  resp_flag = 0;
  //wait until flag == 1
  //Send next request }
public void OnIndication()
{ // Handle request from API...
flag == 1; }
But avoiding the wait function.
`